# How do I output all terms of another taxonomy inside of a custom taxonomy template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below bit of code inside of my custom taxonomy page (taxonomy-apartmentlocation.php). I'm trying to get apartmentlevel taxonomy and output all assigned terms to the page. It's currently only outputing the last term that's assigned. I need it to give me all of them.

And ideas?

```
<?php
  if ($terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'apartmentlevel')) {
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
          echo $term->slug ;
      }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[In the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/), you can read that `get_the_terms` retrieves the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post.

You should use `get_terms()` instead

```
<?php
  if ($terms = get_terms('apartmentlevel',array('hide_empty' => false,))) {
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
          echo $term->slug ;
      }
  }
?>
```

Documentation here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/